# Can't checkout Project (mpp) or Visio (vsdx) files

Tags: 2013, check-out, visio, ms-project

I have library with *'require checkout'* set that contains *mpp* and *vsdx* files.  I have **MS Project** and **Visio 2013 (SP1)** installed locally.

If I choose edit for one of the mpp files, it simply opens in MS project as *read-only* and doesn't allow me to save it (only as a local copy). There's no option to check-out anywhere. Obviously I can check-out manually in SP before opening then check in again afterward but it seems clearly wrong that I'm allowed to click "***Edit***", make changes, but then be unable to save back to SP again (even if you switch back to SP to check-out, Project thinks you've opened it Read Only and won't let you save back to SP).

**For Visio** it's even worse - when I choose Edit for a vsdx file, it opens in Visio as though I can edit it, but when I try to save it says `"UPLOAD FAILED!` You'll need to check-out the file before we can upload changes", and presents a **"CHECK OUT & UPLOAD"** button, but clicking this just gives the same error. Not only that, but the 'Check-Out' button on the Info page does nothing at all, I've confirmed it simply doesn't even send any request to SharePoint to do anything, and no errors are reported anywhere.

However...it seems the Visio problem was temporary and apparently connected to the fact that I have a problem with my internet connectivity status that means it sometimes shows `"No internet access"` even when there is. But in fact my SharePoint server is on a LAN and doesn't require any internet connectivity anyway, so it's clearly a bug that Visio is simply ignoring any request to check-out just because my internet connectivity status is wrong.

***Word/Excel/PowerPoint*** also have an issue with this but at least they tell you that they can't check-out because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a sufficient answer but it's a start. This blog from 25 Jul 2014 states:

> The solution in this case is either use Project Server Web
>   Applications to store the projects and work with them or, choose to
>   sync the document library locally on your computer and open the mpp
>   files from your local copy. This will not set the said lock and you
>   will be able to save the files back to Sharepoint through the sync
>   process.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2014/07/25/mpp-files-stored-in-sharepoint-open-read-only-in-project-client.aspx